# Are There Any Good Tools For Developing CCG Or Other Card Games?

Tags: game-design, playing-cards, game-development

I've been brainstorming a new card game idea for a while, something that could be described as "Cards Against Humanity" meets "Munchkin" but while I mostly have the rules and everything together I have been at a loss to find something to rapidly prototype, print, change, and make the cards?

I would like something that could read from a database, Excel spreadsheet, or something similar and then be able to produce Word document files or PDFs that I could then easily print to be able to beta-test the game with friends.  Ideally you would be able to define the basic components/formats of each card and then just fill in the fields for each.

Anyone know of tools to assist in rapid prototyping and printing of CCG style cards?

Comment: Not sure yet whether I would call this a duplicate or not, but a strongly related question: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/12174/1749

Comment: That does help, I looked at some SVG stuff before but wasn't fully satisfied for what I wanted.

Comment: Not sure why there was an off-topic close vote added to this question, but per the [help/on-topic] page, questions about design are on-topic.

Comment: @SocioMatt This question isn't about game design, but is looking for recommendations for tools. It looks just like our game recommendation questions, and those are off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

NanDeck will do this: http://www.nand.it/nandeck/

Lets you script out card sets, fairly simple to change card sizes, etc.

The website Oil And Rope has a very slick prototyping tool called Paperize: http://paperize.io/beta which lets you upload graphics, use spreadsheet linking, etc. - super cool. Still in beta, but tons of folks love it.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest Strange Eons http://cgjennings.ca/eons/
Whilst not specifically for card games,  it can come in handy.

The  question linked by @shujaa above also has some good links

Comment: That does look promising, well endeavor to test that out and leave some feedback here about it.

Answer (score 1):

While it sounds game-specific, Magic Set Editor is a good tool for this.
http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net/

If you don't like any of the magic card frames (or Yugi-Oh or the couple of others it has) you can create your own - it just takes a little digging around to find out how to do so. I often just use one of the magic card frames, though.

It has a big community of users so there should be plenty of help on how to use it if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found https://dulst.com which bills itself as a platform to create card games.

[image: Dulst]

Answer (score 0):

I made a free extension for Inkscape to create counters or cards from spreadsheets (CSV files) combined with templates drawn in Inkscape (or imported from other applications). Recent versions have built-in PDF export.

https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/299033/inkscape-extensions-boardgame-development

https://github.com/lifelike/countersheetsextension